# Five qubits can be entangled in how many ways?

Tags: entanglement

It is well-known that there are two ways to entangle three qubits (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005115) and nine ways to entangle four qubits (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0109033).

I found in a paper (page 22 left column of https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02431) that there are infinitely many ways to entangle five qubits, but I am not sure how to see or prove this or if this is correct.

Comment: It is already infinitely many ways for four qubits. There is nine classes, but each has some continuous parameter on addition.

Comment: Is there a proof for this assertion?

Comment: I think this is what the Verstraete paper says.